# Пустить весь трафик с Virtualbox VM в VPN соединение на OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vpn, ipfw

На OS X 10.10 запущено стандартное l2tp vpn подключение (галочка "пускать весь трафик" не стоит), в подключенное состоянии через ifconfig определяется как ppp0.
Virtualbox VM c host-only сетью.

Я хочу получить виртуальную машину с изолированной сетью, которая выходит в интернет через l2tp vpn что уже поднята.

Я пытался безуспешно сделать bridge c подключением vboxnet0 адаптера и ppp0. Находил информацию что это сделать нельзя так как ppp подключение нельзя ставить в bridge.

Возможно ли средствами OS X решить мою задачу, например pf firewall?